# Unexpected output from Embedding layer

Tags: python, keras

I've been trying to implement an LSTM in Keras for several hours (using a sequential model with an embedding layer, two LSTM layers, and a dense layer), but I wind up getting different error messages.

From what I can tell, the problem is that the output of the embedding layer has two dimensions instead of three, because I get this value error (`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_2: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2`) when adding the second LSTM layer, and I get the error `assert len(input_shape) >= 3 AssertionError` when I delete the line for adding the second LSTM layer (which means the dense layer has the same issue).

These error occurs before I call the model's "train" method.

My code is here.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Embedding
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras.preprocessing import text
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

# The data in X was preprocessed using Keras' built in pad_sequences.
# Before preprocessing, it consisted of plain lists of integers (which
# were just integers wit a one-to-one map to plain words as strings)

X = pad_sequences(X)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(batch_size=32, input_dim=len(filtered_vocabulary)+1, output_dim=256, input_length=38))
model.add(LSTM(128))
model.add(LSTM(128)) # error occurs in this line
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(len(filtered_vocabulary)+1, activation="softmax")))

model.compile(optimizer = "rmsprop", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(X, X, epochs=60, batch_size=32)
```

I'd be glad if any of you could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because the first LSTM layer only returns the *last* output because you haven't specified `return_sequences=True` in the LSTM layers. This looks like a multi-output setup so you would need to return the LSTM output at *every time step* using that argument for both layers.

Just to be clear, without `return_sequences=True` the shape is `(None, 128)`; with the shape is `(None, 38, 128)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! I added `return_sequences=True` to the layer's arguments and it worked perfectly :)